# too large list parameter to celery

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-messaging, celery

I'm sending gcm notification using the following code.

The `registration_ids` is huge because it is # of recepients.

Is there a way to cut that parameter down somehow?

```
 @shared_task
 def gcm_send_json(registration_ids, data, index=0, **kwargs):

     NUM_REGISTRATION_ID = SETTINGS.get("GCM_MAX_RECIPIENTS")
     range_limit = index + NUM_REGISTRATION_ID

     sub_registration_ids = registration_ids[index: range_limit]

     if not sub_registration_ids:
         return

     _gcm_send_json(sub_registration_ids, data, **kwargs)

     if not kwargs:
         kwargs = {}
     kwargs.update({
         'index': range_limit
     })

     eta = timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
     gcm_send_json.apply_async(args=[registration_ids, data], kwargs=kwargs, eta=eta)
```

I can probably store the registration_ids in redis, and access it from `gcm_send_json` and delete it when I iterate the whole list.
(not sure it's best solution..)

or Could I use a generator?

Answer (score 0):

Storing the large value in Redis, and passing a reference to it is generally the best way to go. 
You can't pass a generator to the celery task.